# How can I disable the Run Hotkey in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I want to use alt+R as a hotkey on a website, but everytime I press it, Run opens instead. Is there any way to disable this feature?

Comment: Win+R opens Run.

Comment: I know Win+R opens Run, but on my computer, alt+R does the same.

Comment: Is this something you've configured? Are you running some sort of third party (OEM) keyboard configuration/remapping utility?

Comment: No, I haven't done anything like that.

Comment: Ah, nevermind. I forgot that I had Start Menu 8 installed on my computer. I uninstalled it, and now alt+R works fine. Thank you.

Comment: Good job figuring it out. It would be nice if you can add that as an answer below and self-accept it, to help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling Start Menu 8 fixes this problem.